# Location of config file for devmode in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, dev-mode

I have a multi module GWT project (say a.gwt.xml, b.gwt.xml, c.gwt.xml) that I am building in eclipse and testing in devmode. All was working well until I deleted one of the gwt module file and associated source. Now when I try to launch devmode from eclipse it fails with the following error message.

Loading modules
   com.fubar.b
      [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/fubar/b.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method

I assume that this means there is a stale reference to the now defunct b.gwt.xml but I can't seem to find it in any of the config files. Any ideas?

At present I am working around this by doing a copy+rename a.gwt.xml -> b.gwt.xml (so there are effectively 2 copies of the a module names a + b) which works fine but compiles 2 copies of same module :(

Answer (score 0):

What I think is your runtime configuration which is gone wrong. Individual projects should be  fine. Open the runtime configuration which you were running and check the entries in GWT! If the module you have deleted still exists here, then you need to remove it.

[Runtime config for project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Pwx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following Video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UW4WSYs1bKE

To rename

1. Right Click on the project.
2. Select Run As ---> Run Configurations.
3. In the Arguments Tab, change the Old Module Names in Program
   Arguments.
4. Also Make sure, in GWT Tab, Selected module name is correct.

**ALREADY I HAVE ANSWERED THIS HERE** : [GWT:how can i rename my module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467578/gwthow-can-i-rename-my-module/9597596#9597596)